# Base Interpreter in Pycharm doesn't show Python from Windows Subsystem for Linux [Ubuntu 20.04]

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am trying to create a project in my `WSL-Ubuntu20.04 (WSL-2)` through the `Pycharm Professional`. And, when I select my desired directory in `WSL` and choose `Virtualenv` from `Environment settings`, there is something wrong in the `Base interpreter` setting. It can't detect the Python interpreter from `WSl-Ubuntu20.04`, rather it shows all the existing interpreters from my `Windows 10 (2004)` machine.

---

- I have already added the valid and working `WSL://UBUNTU2004/usr/bin/python` interpreter from the setting in Pycharm.
- I am using `Ubuntu 20.04` in `WSL-v2` on top of `Windows 10 build 2004`

---

Please see this [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjlko.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating virtual environments with WSL is not supported yet, please vote here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-32853 (thumbs up near the title)